# How to export component layout in KiCad?

Tags: pcb, kicad

I want to export a PDF from KiCad that shows how the components are distributed in a board I designed, with no tracks at all. I want something like [this](https://tpdce.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/amp-2s4-dce_guide-components.pdf).

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

- First click File->Print
- Next select the layers you want to export (if you want only the footprints then the ones highlighted are the ones you want)
- Click preview to see what you did
- Click print when you are ready
- Select "Microsoft XPS printer" (if you are using windows, else I am sure whatever platform you have has something different)